# What are these strips on the Long March 4B?

Tags: identify-this-object, long-march

[image]

[image]

There are yellow square strips arranged semi-erratically on the lower stage of the Long March 4. There are also some on the upper stage. What are they, and do they come off before launch? Why are they only on the lower part of each stage/interstage?

Comment: Those look like the little styrofoam bumpers that you can also see on many cars in Asia. Might they have the same purpose?

Comment: Agree with Jorg W Mittag. Looks like it is there to protect the rocket from bumping into things on the pad ( Maybe they are used when winds are high during assembly? ). In the publicly available pictures of Long March 4B, looks like it is removed after assembly as they are not visible during liftoff.